# boto3 won't install on anaconda-2020.07 when anaconda is installed /apps/anaconda3-2020.07/

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I've been unable to install boto3 on Anaconda3-2020.07. I have tried on AWS linux and Ubuntu Linux. I am installing Anaconda at /apps/anaconda3-2020.07/.

The errors I get are like this:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda boto3
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
```

It then spins for 30 minutes or so, decides that literally hundreds of packages have to be updated, and fails.

I've never seen anything like this before.  boto3 installed with pip with no problem at all.

Comment: Don't install it in the base environment, create a new environment. Pip does not try to solve all the dependencies that conda does, not least that Conda tries to keep a consistent C ABI between packages. You may also want to try [mamba](https://github.com/TheSnakePit/mamba) which is allegedly much faster than conda.

Comment: exact same problem here on MacOS. Never seen that before either. And our team relies on getting `boto3` installed in `base` so that we can then use our private S3-based channel for our own packages.

Comment: This is another reason we stopped using Anaconda on our production system.